# How do I execute a function in my coffee script before the form is submitted (but after button is clicked)?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, onsubmit

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I want a function to be called when someone clicks the submit button, but before the form is submitted.  In my view, I have this submit button …

```
    <%= button_to "Save", { :action => "create" }, :method => :post, :class => 'button' %>
```

Here is what I have in my app/assets/javascripts/users.coffee script …

```
$(document).on 'ready page:load', -> $('.datepicker').datepicker
    dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'

$ ->
  $(".button").submit ->
    hrs = $('#my_object_hour').val();
    min = $('#my_object_minute').val();
    sec = $('#my_object_second').val(); 
    $('#my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_time_in_ms').val((hrs * 60 * 60 + min * 60 + sec) * 1000);
    alert($('#my_object_my_object_times_attributes_0_time_in_ms').val());
    return true;
```

but when I click on the button, the code isn’t executed (the alert is never called).  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: When I change the word"submit" to "click" in the above code, without any other changes, the function is invoked.  Does that support hte theory you have outlined with turbolinks?

Comment: Hold on a sec, is `.button` the *form* or the submit *button*? Sounds like it is the button, the `<form>` triggers submit events, not the button. You should use one of the jQuery-TurboLinks plugins if you're using TurboLinks, otherwise you have to bind to two events (as in your `$(document).on`) or things will behave differently depending on how you get to the page.

Comment: I included the "button_to" code in my question (its at the top).  It is the only such element with a ".button" class.  I'm a little unfamiliar with TurboLinks, I was hoping I could solve this problem entirely through the jQuery in my coffee script.

Comment: `<form>`s trigger submit events, `<button>` and `<input>` don't, you're binding to the wrong thing.